# Generalized abstract factory

Tags: c++, templates, factory-pattern

In *Modern C++ Design*, Alexandrescu describes disadvantages of an object factory, designed as follows:

```
class WidgetFactory
{
public:
    virtual Window* CreateWindow() = 0;
    virtual Button* CreateButton() = 0;
    virtual ScrollBar* CreateScrollBar() = 0;
};
```

One of those disadvantages is unable to create a widget in a generic way:

```
template <class T>
T* MakeRedWidget(WidgetFactory& factory)
{
    T* pW = factory.CreateT(); // huh???
    pW->SetColor(RED);
    return pW;
}
```

or

```
template <class T>
T* MakeRedWidget(WidgetFactory& factory)
{
    T* pW = factory.Create<T>(); // aha!
    pW->SetColor(RED);
    return pW;
}
```

if a creation function were a function template. So, the solution he proposed was a `TypeList`. OK, we have typelists concept now, but it's still not clear how we can create a generic object factory solving the problem about generic widget creation.

```
template <class TList>
class WidgetFactory
{
    //What??
}
```